# Easy way to deal with java package folders?

Tags: java, bash, vim

Is there an easy way to deal with the nested Java package folders on the command line?  I'm always cd-ing (with lots of tab autocomplete) through empty folders (except hidden svn files) in bash and vim.  Are there any tools to make these less frustrating?

org/my/group/team/project/subpackage/TheFileIActuallyWant.java

I'm driven towards Eclipse because of this constant issue.

The worst is CDing all the way down to create a class, and then splitting a vim window with a class in other project.  Yuck!

Comment: I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1217324) that incorporates some of the ideas here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices (IMHO):

- Use a project explorer like [The NERD tree: A tree explorer plugin for navigating the filesystem](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)
- Install in Vim a plugin for quick searching like

  - [FuzzyFinder: buffer/file/command/tag/etc explorer with fuzzy matching](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) or
  - [Command-T: Fast file navigation for VIM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)

Answer (score 1):

If you are mostly editing files and not creating new ones, it may help to symlink all `.java` files into a directory called `quickedit`. Then you can just type `vim quickedit/MyClass.java`, assuming that your class names are mostly unique.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I use `vim \`find -name FileName.java\`` a lot.

Comment: Or you could research if someone has written a bash autocomplete feature that does in-tree-search. `vim MyCl<tab><tab>` looks nice to me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

In your .bash_profile (or equivalent) add:

```
function supercd() { cd $(dirname $(find "$@" -type f | head));}
```

then use it!

```
~ $ supercd temp1
~/temp1/temp2/temp3/temp4 $ ls
test.java
~/temp1/temp2/temp3/temp4 $
```

`supercd` will take you to the first directory containing a file under the directory you specify.

Undoubtedly buggy, but a good start :)

Comment: You are on a mac?  I might start using `function scd() { cd $(find * -name "$@" | head);}`, inspired by you of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AutoJump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki), written by fellow StackOverflow user [static_rtti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164171/static-rtti).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just vim you'll face this kind of problems. Remember that every directory will become a finer grained namespace. Namespaces are good! (From the Zen of Python: Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!).

So, I think it's a good choice to start using eclipse. I think that Java is an imposible language without an IDE.

Comment: Any vim modules to make Java development easier?

Comment: I'd look for some project explorer. But, try to go with eclipse. You'll note the difference.

Comment: I've used Eclipse a lot--I'm actually coding in Scala and I've "noticed the difference" switching back to vim.  Eclipse Scala support is not as nice as Java's.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I've bought a Scala book today! What a coincidence. Any thoughts to share?

Answer (score 0):

you can try 'tree' on *nix systems

Answer (score 0):

Ctags might help you.

```
$ ctags -f ~/.tags -R ~/myprojects/src $JAVA_HOME/src
```

Then tell vim to know where the tag file is.  In your .vimrc:

```
set tags+=~/.tags
```

Now you can jump to declaration parts by pressing `CTRL-]` on any identifiers.

pressing `CTRL-t` to return again to the original position.

Comment: No scala support.  I've used it before for Java.  The problem is I never regenerate my ctags.